# Cannot alter trigger Name on Table because this trigger does not belong to this object

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to alter a trigger. I need to update the table name of the trigger means it is being used for Table-A but now I have to use it for Table-B.

Is there any way to alter the trigger directly, or do I have to remove/drop the lastly used trigger and then create a new one as I am getting the following error:

> Cannot alter trigger Name on Table because this trigger does not belong to this object.

Comment: Yes, you have to drop / re-create. Trigger exists on table1, if you use 'alter trigger for table2' it will try to alter the trigger's code for table2, which doesn't exist, thus the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to drop trigger on table A
then Create same trigger on table B